# End the transaction by performing findById using spring boot and myBatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I think it is bad practice, but I would like to know your reasons why it is.

```
    @Transactional
    public Person update(Person person, Person updated) {
        personMapper.update(updated);
        phoneService.update(person.getPhones(), updated.getPhones());

        return findById(person.getId());
    }
```

Is it okay to do a findById inside a method with the @Transactional tag? Why yes or why not?

Comment: @Transaction can be used where multiple tables needs to be updated under a single transaction, either everything updates or nothing updates. FindById method just runs a select query which need not be in a transaction in most cases.
In some exceptional cases where multiple app's update frequently in db and data consistency is a high priority, there Transactional can be used but this may lead to high response time.

Comment: In some databases, selecting data in a transaction can lead to extra overhead. In this case you are barely selecting a single row so that won't harm much. If you were selecting many rows in Oracle (especially with `SERIALIZABLE`), I would separate them. Anyway, in general try to make the transactions as small as possible to load the engine as little as possible.